# Flutter MacOS: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 13.) Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, dart, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I recently upgraded my computer to Big Sur 11.2.3, I'm running Flutter with the M1 chip, but on the Rosetta architecture, so there should be no issues.

I've tried switching flutter to all of the channels (master, dev, beta, stable) and upgrading.

I've tried running flutter clean, and `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Running `flutter run -d ios` has no issues, but every time I run:

`flutter run -d macos` the build succeeds, and I get:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 13.)
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.
Error launching application on macOS.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this fixed, I ended up deleting everything in the `./macos/` directory except for the `Podfile`, and re-running:

`flutter create --platforms=macos .`

Then:

`flutter run -d macos` succeeded with no issues.

**UPDATE:**

This ended up having to do with having the bluetooth box checked in my macos `.xcworkspace` file. I'll update with more information as I find it.

Comment: Woke up this morning and macos doesn't debug on my project anymore. Nothing changed as far as I know. Getting `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 13.)`. Regenerated the macos files. Ran `cd macos && pod install`. Ran `flutter clean && flutter pub get`. Nothing helped. Did you find any relief?

Comment: @LukePighetti My issue is definitely related to using bluetooth for my macos app. I opened an issue on the flutter repository, but noone was able to reproduce the issue, maybe you can post there IF the issue is related to using the bluetooth capability on macos: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78715 I'm able to run the demo project just fine on another computer, so I'm a little stumped!

Comment: I was able to unblock this issue but I can't remember how I did it. I think I called `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` to make it work